Air india fastest way to attain star alliance gold based on segments flown
I already have Star Alliance Gold status via Turkish airlines.
However these days I fly a lot of flights domestically in India on Air India. Although AI is a part of star alliance these flights give me very few miles per leg and sometimes zero miles on my TK FF program.
I was wondering is there a way to attain status on AI that is based on the total number of legs flown? If so it would make sense for me to apply my flights to an AI FF number instead of a TK FF.
Somehow I fly a lot of short legs so I have a large number of legs flown but not a large number of total miles.
Any thoughts?

I suggest you look into status matching. Not familiar with AI in particular, but many airlines will happily match elite status on other airlines, either immediately or with a challenge (X flights in Y days).

@lambshaanxy Star Alliance officially has a no poaching policy, where airlines are not supposed to match the status of other *A airlines

@Doc TIL. I suppose you could always try to round-trip your status match via a Oneworld/Skyteam airline...
